# Selenium WebDriver findElements() Fails on Single Quotes

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My goal is to parse a block of HTML code like below to obtain the text, comments and replies fields as separate parts of the block:

```
<div id='fooID' class='foo'>
<p>
    This is the top caption of picture's description</p>
<p>
    T=<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/img23.jpg" alt="" width="64" height="108"/>       </p>
<p>
    And here is more text to describe the photo.</p> 
<div class=comments>(3 comments)</div>
<div id='reply13' class='replies'>
   <a href=javascript:getReply('13',1)>Show reply </a></div>
</div>
```

My problem is that Selenium's WebDriver does not seem to support non-string identifiers in the HTML (notice that the class field in the HTML is 'foo' and as opposed to "foo"). From all examples that I have seen in both the Selenium docs and in other SO posts, the latter format is what WebDriver commonly expects.

Here is the relevant part of my Java code with my various (unsuccessful) attempts:

```
java.util.List<WebElement> elementList =    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='foo']"));
java.util.List<WebElement> elementList = (List<WebElement>)  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('.foo')[0]");
java.util.List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'foo')]"));
java.util.List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div." + foo_tag)); // where foo_tag = "'foo'".replace("'", "\'");
java.util.List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("'foo'"));
```

Is there a sure way of handling this? Or is there an alternative, better way of extracting the above fields?
Other info:

1. I'm an HTML noob, but have made efforts to understand the structure of the HTML code/tags
2. Using Firefox (and, accordingly, FirefoxDriver)

Your help/suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid HTML, so Selenium won't have a chance. You should fix it.

You will have a better chance with HTMLAgilityPack:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

It is a little better when it comes to *badly formed* (which this is) HTML.

Below is a SO post which a few different options for a few different languages, with tools like HTMLAgilityPack. You should find a suitable one:

[Options for HTML scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

Comment: I do not have the chance to fix the HTML since I don't have access to it. HTMLAgilityPack looks like a good alternative, but do you know if there're any alternatives of it in Java/C++/Ruby?

Comment: @user1145905, apologies, didn't see you were using Java. There are a few other tools like it, but there is a SO post dedicated to listing all different tools like this, so have edited my post to link to it. In terms of "why" this page loads correctly: thank your browser I would say, it'll attempt to load whatever it's given, whether it's HTML compliant or not.

Comment: Not a problem, thank you @Arran. I will try one of those Java suggestions. Gotcha about the HTML compliance question as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the html specification doesnt know single quotes as far as I know. Therefore you don't have a problem with the Selenum webdriver, the problem is the html.
Do you have the chance to edit the html code?

Comment: I do not have the chance to edit the HTML, unfortunately. If the HTML specification doesn't allow single quotes, how come the page that has this HTML code loads correctly?